# Como pegar geolocalizacao sem usar a api do google que agora esta cobrando uma fortuna?

Tags: php, geolocalização

Preciso pegar latitude e longitude por endereço que o usuário digitar para buscar "nao ip.." mas nao estou conseguindo encontrar uma forma de fazer isso via php sem o google api, pois ele desde de junho esta cobrando uma taxa alta mensal..
acredito que deve ter outras formas de ser feito...

Exemplo:

```
$json_file = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Avenida%20Paulista,%202064,%20Sao%20Paulo"));   


$result = $json_file->results;
$adress = $result->address_components;
$lat    = $adress->geometry->location->lat;
```

Na url do file_get poder colocar outro site que possui essas informações...
mas qual e como??

Comment: Você quer uma alternativa para buscar endereços fora o Google seria isso?

Comment: Isso porem quase,preciso de uma alternativa para buscar latitude e longitude e correlação a determinado endereço...
ou seja enviar o endereço e me retornar o valores de latitude e longitude isso tudo utilizando o php.